# TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float' even if already parsed with float()

Tags: python

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
#1 kilogram : 2.205 pounds = x : y
#from __future__ import division

z=0

print "****The nicest kilos to pounds converter on Earth****"
while z==0:
    select=input("1)Kilos to pounds\n2)Pounds to kilos\n")
    if select==1:
        y=float(raw_input('Kilos: '))
        print "Is %f pounds\n" % y*2.205
        z=int(raw_input('Exit? [0/1] '))
    elif select==2:
        y=float(raw_input('Pounds: '))
        print "Is %f kilos\n" % y/2.205
        z=int(raw_input('Exit? [0/1] '))

print "Bye Bye!"
```

Why do I keep getting TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'?
Isn't y already converted to float after catching the input? I really can't find what's wrong with this code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are interpolating into the string *first*, then multiplying the result:

```
>>> y = 2.5
>>> "Is %f pounds\n" % y*2.205
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

This happens because the `%` operator has an equal [operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) with multiplication, and the operators are executed from left to right in that case.

Put parenthesis around the multiplication:

```
>>> "Is %f pounds\n" % (y*2.205)
'Is 5.512500 pounds\n'
```

Do the same for your division line:

```
print "Is %f kilos\n" % (y/2.205)
```

Alternatively, use [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) to format your values:

```
print "Is {:f} pounds\n".format(y * 2.205)
```

and

```
print "Is {:f} kilos\n".format(y / 2.205)
```